# anyconnect client, start before logon, and dual boot

Tags: multi-boot, cisco-vpn-client

I want to install the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client on my personal laptop to access the network at work.  However, my employer requires me to install "start before logon" in addition to the VPN client.

My laptop is dual boot (Win 7, Ubuntu 12.04).  Is there any chance installing "start before logon" will screw up the dual boot?

Clarification:

*With Start Before Logon (SBL) enabled, the user sees the AnyConnect GUI logon dialog before the Windows® logon dialog box appears. This establishes the VPN connection first. Available only for Windows platforms, Start Before Logon lets the administrator control the use of login scripts, password caching, mapping network drives to local drives, and more. You can use the SBL feature to activate the VPN as part of the logon sequence. SBL is disabled by default.*

Comment: You will have to explain what `start before logon` is exactly.

Comment: Address all clarification within the question itself.  All the feature does is connects to the VPN before you log into your user, there is no possible way, that they can verify the setting iss enabled nor would it harm your personal computer if you were to enable it.

Comment: Ramhound, thanks for the advice re SBL and the tip re posting clarifications.

Comment: To be clear `SBL` simply starts a Windows service before the user logs into their account. A Winows service cannot effect a Linux installation.

Comment: Right.  That's what I suspected.  Right now I'm both trying to sell my house and finish a project before moving to a new job out of state, and I don't have time to tinker, even if I think the chance of failure is low.  Thanks again.